# issue with displaying png images of tree layout are not getting displayed in safari browser(windows)

Tags: d3.js

.png images of D3 tree layout are not getting displayed in safari browser(windows).In Firefox and chrome it is working fine.where as other png images which are not part of tree layout are displayed

In index.html i have this code where images are defined.images which are not part of tree layout they are getting displayed

```
            <!DOCTYPE HTML>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <html>
            <head>

            <link href="css/LatencySummary.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link href="css/NetworkTopology.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="networkTopology.js"></script>

            <title>JetPort UI</title>

            <style type="text/css">
            .node {
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .overlay {
                background-color: #fff;
            }

            .node circle {
                fill: #fff;
                stroke: #fff;
                stroke-width: 1.5px;
            }

            .node text {
                font-size: 10px;
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }

            .link {
                fill: none;
                stroke: #ccc;
                stroke-width: 2px;
            }

            .templink {
                fill: none;
                stroke: red;
                stroke-width: 3px;
            }

            .ghostCircle.show {
                display: block;
            }

            .ghostCircle,.activeDrag .ghostCircle {
                display: none;
            }
            </style>

            </head>
            <body onload="loadGraph()">
                <div id="bg">
                    <img id="imgBG" src="image/oceanBackground.png" alt="" height="100%"
                        width="100%">
                </div>

                <div id="titleDiv" style="height: 35px;">
                    <img id="logo" src="image/appLogo_white.png" height="100%" width="5%"
                        align="left"> <span
                        style="position: relative; top: 15px; left: 250px"> <font
                        face="Arial" size="5" color="white">Shooting Game Application</font>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <svg id="mySvg" width="10" height="10">
                 <defs id="mdef">

                     <filter id="webserver" x="0%" y="0%" width="120%" height="140%">
                        <feImage xlink:href="image/web-servernew.png" />
                    </filter>

                    <filter id="container" x="0%" y="0%" width="120%" height="140%">
                        <feImage xlink:href="image/container-osnew.png" />
                    </filter>
                    <filter id="containerCollapse" x="0%" y="0%" width="120%"
                        height="160%">
                        <feImage xlink:href="image/container-os-collapse.png" />
                    </filter>      
                     <filter id="appserver" x="0%" y="0%" width="120%" height="140%">
                        <feImage xlink:href="image/App-servernew.png" />
                    </filter>

                    <filter id="virtualMac" x="0%" y="0%" width="200%" height="200%">
                        <feImage xlink:href="image/virtual-machine.png" />
                    </filter>
                     <filter id="virtualMacCollapse" x="0%" y="0%" width="200%"
                        height="200%">
                        <feImage xlink:href="image/virtual-machine_collapse.png" />
                    </filter>

                     <filter id="dbserver" x="0%" y="0%" width="120%" height="140%">
                        <feImage xlink:href="image/DB-servernew.png" />
                    </filter>   
                    <filter id="network" x="0%" y="0%" width="200%" height="300%">
                        <feImage xlink:href="image/network.png" /> 
                    </filter>
                    <filter id="networkCollapse" x="0%" y="0%" width="200%" height="300%">
                        <feImage xlink:href="image/network-collapse.png" /> 
                    </filter>   
                    <filter id="loadbalancer" x="0%" y="0%" width="150%" height="200%">
                        <feImage xlink:href="image/Dynamic-load-Balancer.png" /> 
                    </filter>
                    <filter id="storage" x="0%" y="0%" width="150%" height="200%">
                        <feImage xlink:href="image/network_storage.png" /> 
                    </filter>
                   </defs>
             </svg>

                <div id="tableDiv">
                    <table class="jumbotron" bgcolor="#B1C1CB" style="margin-left: 200px;">

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div id="progressDiv">
                                    <img id="progress" src="image/progressBar.gif"> <font
                                        face="Arial" size="2" style="font-weight: bold" color="#0D0C0C">Loading...</font>
                                </div>
                                <div id="graph" class="chart" align="right" style="height: 250px"></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div style="height: 2px; text-align: left;">
                                    <span style="position: relative; right: -0.5%; font-weight: bold">
                                        <font face="Arial" size="3" color="#040404">Network
                                            Topology</font>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-left: 5px">
                                <div id="tree-container" onclick="divClick(event)"></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dynamicData.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Again, would you mind posting some code?

Comment: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797521/is-it-possible-to-increase-gap-for-one-of-the-node-of-my-tree-layout-in-d3-js   .here i posted the code.code for index.html(home page)i updated in above query

Comment: Could you please post the *relevant* parts of your *current* code? In particular where you're adding the images.

Comment: this is the image addition logic.style("filter", function(d, i) {
     if (nodes[i].type == "vm") {
      if (d.children == 'undefined' || d.children == null) {
       return "url(#virtualMacCollapse)";
      } else {

Comment: issue is with <filter id="storage" x="0%" y="0%" width="150%" height="200%">
          <feImage xlink:href="image/network_storage.png" /> 
      </filter>                   all the images which are not added using above logic are getting displayed but which are added using above logic are not displayed

Comment: You need to use an `image` element, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567809/how-to-add-an-image-to-an-svg-container-using-d3-js

Comment: Cool, I'll add that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SVG, you need to use `image` elements to display images. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567809/how-to-add-an-image-to-an-svg-container-using-d3-js) for more information.