# how to make child nodes of tree layout collapsing into parent node when clicked

Tags: d3.js

how to make child nodes  tree layout collapsing into its parent node on click.as of now when clicked on the parent node ,child nodes are collapsing into some where in the page.code of my tree can be found here .In similar way child node should expand from its parent node

[Increasing gap between nodes of my D3 tree layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797521/is-it-possible-to-increase-gap-for-one-of-the-node-of-my-tree-layout-in-d3-js)

Comment: There are plenty of examples of this on the web -- how is what you're trying to do different? Also, you haven't posted any code.

Comment: hi Lars,thanks for responding found the solution it was simple,we have changed the orientation of the layout but didnt changed the order of cordinates for node.enter and node.exit,now we modified its working. regarding the code,i have posted  the link above in my query which contains the code,on click it redirect us to the code.i might not have posted the link in proper order

Answer (score 0):

the order in which project cordinates are given,

in the same order cordinates should be passed for node.enter and node.exit for collapsing into the parent node and expanding from the parent node as shown in the scree shot[image]